# Javascript string representation of HTML element

Tags: javascript

I have a `<span>` element as follows:

```
<span style="position: absolute; top: -42px; right: 2px; z-index: 100;" data-ng-click="DeleteImageProperties(img.vehicleId, img.vehiclePhotoId, img.fileName)">×</span>
```

And I am reading this `<span>` like this:

```
var outerHTML = itemelement[0];
```

it returns the above output, but I want to convert it to string. If I use:

```
outerHTML.toString()
```

it just returns:

```
[object HTMLSpanElement]
```

How could I get a pure string representation of my `<span>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you really want `outerHTML.outerHTML`, as it's clearly not the outer HTML, but a DOM node in a variable with a strange name

Comment: how to convert it to a string?